# How do I extract arguments in a function (written as a string) in R?

Tags: r, string, function, parsing, parameters

Let suppose I have defined a function by `f <- function(x,y,z) {...}`.

I would like to be able to transform an expression calling that function into a list of the parameters called by that function; it is the opposite of the `do.call` function.

For example, let us say I have such a function `f`, and I also have a string `"f(2,1,3)"`.
How can I transform the string `"f(2,1,3)"` into the list of the parameters `list(x=1,y=2,z=3)`?

Comment: I believe you wish to use some combination of `eval` and `parse/deparse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've parsed your character string into an R expression, use `match.call()` to match supplied to formal arguments.

```
f <- function(x,y,z) {}
x <- "f(1,2,3)"

ee <- parse(text = x)[[1]]
cc <- match.call(match.fun(ee[[1]]), ee)
as.list(cc)[-1]
# $x
# [1] 1
# 
# $y
# [1] 2
# 
# $z
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```r
f <- function(x,y,z) {...}
s <- "f(x = 2, y = 1, z = 3)"

c <- as.list(str2lang(s))
c[-1]
# $x
# [1] 2
# 
# $y
# [1] 1
# 
# $z
# [1] 3
```

I was looking for a solution to this a while ago in order to reconstruct a function call from a string. Hopefully this will be of use to someone who is looking for a solution to a similar problem.